# I'm trying to make a number minigame and how do i make the bot tell the member if their to high or low than the number that the bot made?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is the code that I have below. Say if the number is 50, how do i make the bot say that they guessed lower (49 or below) or they guessed higher (51 and above) Thanks!

````
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith(">numbergame"):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send("Guess the number from 0-100 by writing the number in this channel!")

        number1 = random.randint(1,100)
        print(number1)
        
        number2 = str(number1)

        def check(m):
            return m.content == number2 and m.channel == channel
        
        msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
        await channel.send(f"Correct answer! {message.author.mention}" .format(msg))
    else:
      await bot.process_commands(message)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code but next time please ask a real question. This is a community website and we are asking or answering questions for all of the members.

```
import asyncio

async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith(">numbergame"):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send("Guess the number from 0-100 by writing the number in this channel!")

        number = random.randint(1,100)

        def check(m):
            return m.content.isdigit() and m.channel == channel and m.author == message.author
    
        while True:
            try:
                msg = await bot.wait_for('message', timeout=30.0, check=check)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                return await channel.send("You are late to guess")
            guess = int(msg.content)
            if guess == number:
                return await channel.send(f"Correct answer! {message.author.mention}")
            elif guess > number:
                await channel.send("You guess was to high.")
            elif guess < number:
                await channel.send("Your guess was to low")
    else:
        await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: This worked so thank you! However, I did ask a real question, sorry if I wasted your time.